# Origen de "mindundi"

Tags: etimología, españa, sustantivos

Hoy he tenido ocasión de usar la voz *mindundi* en una frase, y me he quedado preguntándome el origen de dicha palabra. Yo pensaba que igual me encontraba con una de esas voces que son mucho más antiguas de lo que aparentan, pero...

- No aparece en el NTLLE ni en la edición del DLE de 2001, luego su inclusión es muy reciente.
- No aparece en el diccionario etimológico de Corominas.
- No aparece en ejemplos en el CORDE. En el CREA el más antiguo es de 1992:

  > *"El Butano" se puede tirar ocho horas haciendo llamadas de teléfono para averiguar si un "mindundi" comió con otro "mindundi".*
- No hay ninguna ficha sobre la palabra en el *Fichero general* de la RAE.
- No aparece en la web de Etimologías de Chile.

Se define así:

> **[mindundi](https://dle.rae.es/mindundi)**
>
> 1. m. y f. despect. coloq. *Esp.* Persona insignificante, sin poder ni influencia.

¿Cuál puede ser entonces el origen de esta palabra? ¿Se trataría de una voz inventada simplemente por su sonoridad?

Comment: Interesante. A este lado del charco nunca la he oído. ¿un mindundi es un **fulano** cualquiera o un **donnadie**?

Comment: @DGaleano tiene una connotación despectiva, así que es sinónima de _donnadie_.

Comment: ¡No oí en mi vida ese término!

Comment: @Charlie ¿hace cuanto que lo conoces?¿es un término usado en tu pais?

Comment: @user2325442 es una palabra exclusiva de España, al parecer y a juzgar por la definición. Ignoro desde cuándo la conozco.

Answer (score 4):

Tras investigar un poquito creo que he conseguido acotar bastante el posible origen de la palabra, que al final ha resultado tener más antigüedad de la que parecía en un principio.

Me resultó curioso, en primer lugar, que los dos primeros textos que hacen referencia a la palabra lo hagan en el ámbito del teatro, a principios del siglo XX, y que aparezcan de repente (sin ningún caso previo) con apenas unos meses de diferencia. Son los siguientes:

> Era el año 1893 y el mes de Diciembre; compañía de zarzuela grande; teatro do San Fernando, de Sevilla.
>   En la compañía figuraban Eutalia González, María Pizarro, Dolores Abril, Amalia Sabater y, de ellos, Valentín González, José Lacarra, Eduardo Garro, Juanito Beltrami y *servidor* en clase de *mindundi*, todos dirigidos por D. Francisco Villegas y ei maestro Federico Reparaz.
>
> **El Heraldo de Madrid.** 17/7/1908, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000568959&page=4&search=mindundi&lang=es).

Por el texto se desprende que quien escribe era un actor en un papel de relleno.

> Esto no tiene nada de particular. Lo curioso es, que la mayoría de los «sola-crticos» se *pirran* por ir *oficialmente* á un estreno, sin perjuicio de firmar la *critica* con
>   un seudónimo. Esto que parece un rasgo de modestia no lo es la mayoría de los casos, pues el autor de la critica —¡que tiene cuando menos un par de piececitas de cada género!— se encarga de poner en claro, cuál es el nombre verdadero de *Mundundi chico*— este es el seudónimo.
>   Y yo digo, si los lectores de un periódico están acostumbrados á leer á su critico —único y verdadero— qué caso pueden hacer de *Mindundi*, ó de *X*, famoso este último por escribir en casi todos los periódicos europeos.
>
> **El País (Madrid).** 19/10/1908, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002339223&page=4&search=mindundi&lang=es).

Interesante el uso de "mundundi", pero he buscado y de esa variante no hay apenas registros. El caso es que, como se ve, aparecen dos artículos en dos diarios diferentes usando el término "mindundi", uno de ellos en mayúsculas como haciendo alusión a un nombre o apellido.

Así que intenté centrar el tiro restringiendo la búsqueda al ámbito teatral, y por fin di con una tesis doctoral titulada *[Historia del teatro olvidado: la revista (1864-2009)](https://hera.ugr.es/tesisugr/18510413.pdf)*, escrita por Juan José Montijano Ruiz y dirigida por Concepción Argente del Castillo Ocaña, de la Facultad de Filosofía y Letras de la Universidad de Granada. En esta tesis se nos habla de una obra teatral titulada *La alegre trompetería*, estrenada en Madrid a las diez de la noche del 14 de octubre de 1907 en el Teatro Eslava.

Como parte del argumento se traslada al espectador al club que da título a la obra, donde se reúnen sus socios para hablar de sus conquistas. El presidente del club es Francisco Mindundi, que lleva cinco años seguidos siendo presidente dado que es quien más conquistas ha realizado durante el año. Los demás recelan de él y contratan a un tal Saturnino Gazapo, una persona con un imán para las mujeres, para que le derrote. Este, con la ayuda de su secretario Jeremías Peluche, quien odia a las mujeres porque la suya le engañó, consigue finalmente derrotar a Mindundi y hacerse con la presidencia del club.

Hemos de fijarnos en que todos los apellidos son palabras corrientes: *mindundi*, *gazapo* y *peluche*. Esto indica que "mindundi" debía ser una palabra que ya se conocía en 1907. Sin embargo, esta obra tuvo bastante popularidad y se la recuerda por su cuplé de "La regadera". Por tanto, esta obra pudo darle a la voz *mindundi* la popularidad que hasta entonces le había sido negada, habiéndose restringido su uso hasta entonces al mundo del teatro.

Lo malo es que todo esto no nos da pistas realmente de cuál es su posible origen verdadero. Yo entiendo que simplemente es una voz de origen expresivo, posiblemente hecha a propósito para asimilarse a alguna voz latina (como *mundi*, por ejemplo, de la que pudo salir el *mundundi* que vimos antes, y de ahí pasar a *mindundi*). Si su origen está en el mundo de la revista, los inicios de esta en España fueron a partir de 1865, por lo que la voz no debe tener mucha más antigüedad que esa. Pero esto ya son conjeturas.

Comment: Interesantísima investigación.

Answer (score 1):

Mindundi tiene un origen árabe del sigle 15. Una persona sin nada se dice en arabe "min dun chay" o " min dun" que significa "min" (sin), "dun" (ninguna), "chay" (cosa).
Un "min dun" es una persona a la que le han quitado todo

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Karim. ¿Podrías añadir alguna referencia que respalde lo que expones? ¿La sílaba final "di" indica algo más?

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco he visto un vídeo en el que el señorJosé Manuel Rodríguez Ramos explica que en árabe hay una palabra para explicar el hecho de que a una persona le quiten todos sus bienes materiales, mindun.

Comment: Buenos días, María, bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías añadir el enlace al video correspondiente e incluir alguna referencia de ese señor como autoridad de la lengua española o árabe?

Answer (score 0):

Podria proceder de la frase Árabe "min duni din" cuyo significa es:
Min(sin) dun(ningún o ninguna) din( juicio, costumbre o religión)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio. ¿Podrías añadir alguna referencia que respalde lo que expones?